# What's the difference between the :web and :app groups in capistrano/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm setting up different `capistrano` groups in a rails app that I inherited and I was wondering what the different between the :app group and the :web group was in `capistrano/rails`. From what I can tell, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano's roles help you run tasks only on certain servers (if you have multiple servers). In your case you can use `capistrano-sidekiq` gem and create a capistrano role (a server basically) which only runs sidekiq jobs with:

```
set :sidekiq_role, [:workers]
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq#different-number-of-processes-per-host) and [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#server-roles)

Comment: right. my question is really about the different tasks that are in `capistrano/rails`. so, if I have a `:app` server and a `:web` server, what parts of rails get installed on each? (I removed the sidekiq part because that was a red herring). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any good documentation on this, so here's my attempt to provide it:

The roles are related but they are used differently by different tasks

Database and migration tasks are run on servers with `db` roles

Asset tasks are run on servers with `web` roles.

Bundle tasks are run on all servers.

Passenger server tasks are run on servers with `app` roles

Without reviewing the cap gem too thoroughly I believe that most of the deploy tasks are run on all roles by default.

The good news is that most of this is configurable, for instance it is recommended to: `set :migration_role, :app` and there are similar role configs for `assets_roles` `passenger_roles` and `bundle_roles`.

You can see from the above that:

- The web role is intended for front end proxying servers i.e. apache/nginx
- The app role is for the application server, i.e. passenger/puma
- The db role is intended for the database server, although it is not really recommended to use it (https://github.com/capistrano/rails#recommendations)
- It is assumed that code will be deployed to all roles

For the most basic setup where everything is on one server you probably want to configure all roles on that server.